# Many to Many field

Tags: python, django

Создал модель Technology в которой только одно поле Technology. В модели work добавил Technologies связанное many to many c Technology. Добавил 2 Technology(html, css), добавил объект work с этими двумя. Но ни на сайте не в shell этого нет.

shell
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в бд в work тоже нет, хотя добавились таблицы work_technologies и technologies.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В админке я добавил эти технологии 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выводе на сайте пишет что их нет, хотя всё остальное выводит 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В шаблон передаю так

```
{% for foo in card %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front"><img src="{{ foo.Photo.url }}"></div>
        <div class="back">
            <h1>{{ foo.Site_name }}</h1>
            <h2>Date: {{ foo.Year }}</h2>
            <h2><a href="{{ foo.Real_Link }}">Link : {{ foo.Link }}</a></h2>
            <h2>Technologies:{{ foo.Technologies}}</h2>
            <p>Description: {{ foo.Description }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

В card у меня все work.objects.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, должно заработать. Почитайте про [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?)

```
<h2>Technologies: 
{% for technology in foo.Technologies.all %}
    {{ technology }}<br/>
{% endfor %}</h2>
```